# Ngbootstrap accordian isOpen is not provided by accordian-group element. How to close or expand all elements in an accordion?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

The following code was from an online example and I wanted to use the logic here in a similar accordion in my app.

```
<div class="container">
  <p>notifications works!</p>
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Open By Default" [isOpen]="open">
      <p>Open By Default</p>
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Disabled">
      <p>Disabled</p>
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="with isOpenChange">
      <p>Open Event</p>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

But on the `isOpen` I get the following error:

```
angualr ngbootstrap accordian  isOpen is not provided by accordian-group element
Library: @angular/core@14.2.3
```

What am I doing wrong ? If this is not the proper way to expand/collapse all in an accordion I am very open to suggestions.

Comment: I believe that this `accordion` component is from [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/accordion?tab=overview#opened) but not ng-bootstrap. And please specify with library version that you used.